# Why does Action event on a button does not call the controller function

Tags: ember.js

I have an index.html file which has a button with an action handler.

```
<button {{action 'modules'}} > press </button>
```

But nothing happens when I press the button.

please look at the code at jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/OREMORe/1/edit

Feel free to correct any other inconsistencies.
Appreciate any help. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do it like [this](http://jsbin.com/OREMORe/7/). Please note that there were a few things wrong with your code:

1) You handlebars code with your button in it was not wrapped in a handlebars `script` tag
2) You're 'modules' template was in the application template
3) You did not include valid links to the necessary libraries
4) There was not `rootElement` specified for the Application
5) You tried to access `ModulesController` in the `ApplicationRoute`. I inserted a redirect to 'modules'
6) You tried to access `module` in your `{{#each}}` loop, but that does not exists in your model. What you want is `content`.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
{{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="modules">
    <ul>
      {{#each content}}
      <li>{{this}}</li>
      {{/each}}
        <button {{action 'modules'}} > press </button>
    </ul>
  </script>
```

And:

```
var Test1 = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: 'body',
    ready: function() {
        console.log("App ready1");
    }
});

Test1.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('modules');
  }
});


Test1.Router.map( function() {
    this.route('modules');
});

Test1.ModulesController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        modules: function() {
            console.log('clicked the button');
/*            this.transitionToRoute('modules');*/
        }
    }
});
Test1.ModulesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return ['item1', 'item2'];
     }
});
```